# Cannot connect to remote node using torsocks on macOS

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

```
$ torsocks /Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monero-wallet-gui
2021-03-18 18:33:54.441 E error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
```

In "Settings", "Node", I copy/pasted an onion address to "Address" and configured port to `18081`.

Comment: Not an answer but I run into the same issue on macos here. Same behavior when using `--socks5-proxy` instead of torsocks. Monero GUI version: `0.17.1.9-3ca5f10 (Qt 5.12.8)` When trying to connect to any .onion remote node, when clicking `Connect` in the GUI, this error in the log:
`E error: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)`

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment. Have you tried setting DNS_PUBLIC=tcp? That way DNS requests are routed through Tor which is required if you use a .onion remote node (or don't want to leak your DNS requests). You would then launch the GUI like this:<br>
`DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks /Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monero-wallet-gui`

Comment: Issue is still present… created [issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/3552) on GitHub.